# TextView contents is lost after changing screen orientation

Tags: android, lifecycle

Observing my application behavior in Android emulator, I see that EditText contents is preserved after changing screen orientation (Ctrl+F11). But TextView contents is reset to its initial value and doesn't keep latest information set by the program. Is this behavior by definition? What can I do to keep this contents?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use this property in your **TextView** `android:freezesText="true"`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be enough. What else did you have to add?

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `savedInstanceBundle` to keep hold of the data by overriding two methods inside your activity, similar to below:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // Save state to the savedInstanceState
  savedInstanceState.putString("MyString", textview.getText());

}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // Restore state from savedInstanceState
  String myString = savedInstanceState.getString("MyString");
  textview.setText(myString);
}
```

Add your items to the `Bundle` in `onSaveInstanceState`, and read them back in during `onRestoreInstanceState`. This works in a similar way to passing values through intents when creating activities.

Answer (score 3):

When orientation changes happen, Android reload the Activity hence destroying most information like TextView changes. You will need to override `onSaveInstanceState()`, which will run before the screen orientation change happens. Then you will have access to it in your `Bundle` that is passed into `onCreate`. You should also reference this to understand the [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) Life cycle.