# Used a file chooser, want to have a TextView that displays chosen file

Tags: android, textview, filechooser

Background info:

So I have a file chooser portion that chooses and does a toast that indicates the file selected, I would like to have a essentially what the toast says but in a indicated TextView object.

Code:

```
//File selection code
// Create a file instance from the URI
    final File file = FileUtils.getFile(uri); 
    Toast.makeText(FileTransfer.this, "File Selected: " + file.getAbsolutePath(),  
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Is there a dynamic text adapter I can use or what is a way to going about doing this?

Comment: create a view with a textview in it then set the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your layout XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fileNameTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

and then in your Java code (if part of an `Activity` context) instead of the `Toast` logic:

```
TextView fileNameTextView = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.fileNameTextView);
fileNameTextView.setText(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Used this setup.

Comment: Actually, how do I keep it from going away when I switch layouts, specifically Landscape > Portrait layouts?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12822267/textview-contents-is-lost-after-changing-screen-orientation, the answer with Java code should do it for you.

Comment: Yes. You will probably have to make `fileNameTextView` a class field and instantiate it in the `onCreate` method.

Comment: Did you mean the android:freezesText line? I used that one and it worked. Thanks for pointing out the thread!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question on Voicu's answer, you can set screenOrientation in the Manifest file.

```
<activity
   android:name=".."
   android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```